# jQuery :data() selector not working after being set

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I expect to match at least one element, but I get zero. What am I doing wrong?

```
$("tr:first").data("aaa", "333"); // setting the data
console.log($("tr:data(aaa == "333")")); // reading the data
```

Comment: I wasn't aware there was such a selector. Could this be from a plugin?

Comment: @BoltClock https://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/
The thing is.. that you are correct. i missed it.. it jQueryUI. however - it's not alerting me that the selector is invalid in the context.
(I expect to get "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: data")

Comment: The documentation doesn't specify that you can use such a selector, only `$("tr:data(key)")` seems to be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
console.log($("tr:data(aaa, 333)"));
```

to this only:

```
console.log($("tr:data(aaa)").data('aaa') === "333");
```

---

If you are looking to filter the `tr`s then use `.filter()` method:

```
$("tr:data(aaa)").filter(function(i, el){
  return el.data('aaa') === "333"
}).css('color', 'red');
```

---

You are actually trying to set the data value again to the `tr` element in the console.

```js
$('span').data('aaa', 3333);
var value = $('span:data(aaa)').data('aaa')
$('pre').html(value == 3333)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<span>3333</span>

<pre>pre</pre>
```

Comment: better to do like `console.log($("tr:data(aaa)") == "333"); // reading the data`

Comment: This is a condition, not a selector.. wont help me :\

Comment: 1. thanks!
2. what i am trying to do, is to iterate some numbers, and in each round, to get a `<tr>` which its `data-index` is matching the current number. the `index` value is preset using `$(tr).data(index,number)`